Are the Blues Brothers actual brothers?
Are the Blues Brothers, Jake and Elwood, actual biological siblings?
Is "Blues" their actual surname?
Are they like The Righteous Brothers, who aren't actual brothers, and neither has the surname Righteous?
Or are they like The Everly Brothers, who were actual brothers and were really called Everly?

It's a fair question, they're not even slightly blue.

You know that Blues is also a music genre, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues

Pre-film
The original characters are stated to be biological brothers. The 1978 album Briefcase Full of Blues has a biography of the two Blues Brothers. It states that Jake is the older brother of Elwood. No mention is made of their shared parentage, so it's possible that they're half-brothers.

Jake had a vision. It was his, the only real one he'd ever had, and he
clung to it. There had been too many messy gas station holdups with
only some green stamps and a case of Valvoline to show for the risk.
Joliet Jake had always been full of schemes. But this was different;
it played across his tiled cell wall 24 hours a day. And the ending
was always the same - Jake and his younger brother Elwood cruising out
of Calumet City, Ill., with the sun in their shades and a full tank of
gas. He absentmindedly rubbed his Buddha belly; even on a diet of jail
food and Chesterfields, Jake had gained weight. Someday they'd have a
penthouse on Lake Shore Drive... float around with bourbons and
blonds. It was out there for the taking and Jake could smell it like
ozone in damp air.
It had always been the blues. Even back in the Rock Island City
orphanage (that sweaty kid factory with the black windows) Jake and
Elwood were saved by the music. Actually, saved by a gray-haired
janitor everybody called Curtis. He wore these sinister midnight
shades, a narrow black tie and a porkpie hat the he kept pushed back
on his head. Curtis wrapped his waxy brown hands around his guitar
neck and played the most dangerous blues this side of Robert Johnson.
The nuns scorched their days with holy threats and Curtis rescued them
by night. Down in the coolness of his basement he taught the brothers
the blues.

Various licenced properties (such as The Elwood Blues Review and The Blue Brothers: First Contact Stage Musical) are pretty clear that their family name is 'Blues'.

Jake and Elwood Blues are conditionally released from Joliet Detention
Facility and are conscripted to the US military on direct orders from
the Commander in Chief.

1980 film.
We get some backstory regarding their time in the orphanage in the film's official novelisation by Miami Mitch (Glazer) and the tie-in memorabilia book Blues Brothers: Private by Judith Jacklin.
In these we learn that they aren't, in fact, biologically related. Elwood is a foundling and Jacob Papageorge is an orphan.

Sister Mary Stigmata cradled the silent baby close to her. Funny, the poor little thing hadn’t cried all night. In fact he hadn’t made any noise at all since Officer Delaney brought him by after dinner. The sister shook her head sadly. Delaney said some salesman had pulled up to a newsstand and tossed a dime for the Gazette. Instead of the newspaper, somebody had dropped this sleeping baby through the open window of the car, into the salesman’s lap. Sister Mary had named him Elwood because he was the fifth child left at the Saint Helen of the Blessed Shroud Orphanage that week, and E was the fifth letter of the alphabet (it was a pet system of hers.)
Someone coughed at one end of the huge room, and Sister Mary gazed down the long row of sleeping toys. Bits of dreams and muttered nightmares escaped into the dorm. The place was deep with sleep. The orphans insisted that the room, with its high dim ceilings, hid scary shadows. But it was more a barracks than a haunted house; even fear was too romantic for this building. It was functional, aid the sister and her fellow nuns were caring, if impersonal. Still, it was the only house and family these kids had. And right now the home was jammed; not a free bed in sight. Well, the sister couldn’t stand there and hold Elwood forever. He’d just have to double up with somebody.
Suddenly Sister Mary knew she was being watched! She whirled around, and staring straight at her—that amazing hustler’s spark in his two-and-a-half-year-old face—was little Jake Papageorge. Wide awake and calm as an undertaker, he checked out the nun and the child in her arms.
“All right, Mr. Papageorge,” the sister said, somehow knowing he could understand her, “it looks as though you have a new friend.” She placed Elwood in bed with Jake. I’m sure you two will get along famously.” Jake made room for the infant as if he’d slept there forever. As if they were brothers.

and



He is later seen to be using the name Jake E. Blues in official documents.



Elwood's surname was assigned as Elwood Delaney (after the Patrolman who took him into custody).



Less than ten years later, and while still at the orphanage, he officially changed his name to Elwood Delaney Blues.




Love the answer (+1), but would it be possible to get a little more verbiage about where
exactly those document pictures were taken from? I've seen the movie probably hundreds of times, and I don't remember any document shots like that. The only ones I remember at all were when Jake signs his name with an X in the first scene to get out of prison, and when they are getting their tax reciept at the end.

Oh yeah, there was also the SCMODS display of Elwood's record they showed in the police car right before the mall chase, but none of these pics look anything like that either.

@T.E.D. - Those images and documents were created for the tie-in book; https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1930947.Blues_Brothers

Perhaps that could be clearer in the answer? Either way, might consider adding a screenshot from the SCMODS display? Since that's actually from the movie and not a tie-in creation.

"No mention is made of their shared parentage, so it's possible that they're half-brothers." Or they could just consider themselves to be brothers due to be raised together.

@Acccumulation - Indeed. And the tie-in materials would suggest that's actually the case.
